# Ajax call for tooltip methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, tooltip

I have a number of images on my website, with a database with corresponding information. I am at a loss though as to how I should go about generating tooltips for this information.

I thought that using the div ID to do an ajax call to the database would be pretty clean and fairly quick. But I havent really had enough field experience to know if this is the best way to go about it.

I was also thinking that a script could run on page load, populating some elements with the information, which a tooltip would then access. But again, same question, is this the best way to do this?

I would like some possible solutions and why they are better/best with some kind of example code if that is okay.

UPDATE: 
This is the code I have so far. So now I need an Ajax call to the database to pull the info? How would I go about that? I have looked at the API but I am drawing a blank on implementation. I need a kick in the right direction.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.pane').each(function(){
    if( $(this).is(':empty') ) {
    $(this).append( "<p>Test</p>" );
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I would have brought the tooltip info for visible images on screen at the start of page load itself and for remaining images as per demand, sending the ajax call.

Comment: So pre-load the info into hidden elements or the DOM object title? And then just display them on hover?

Comment: into hidden element/DOM title attr or even js object(would be better as you already gonna get it in some js object), but limited to say first 20 images and for rest as per demand get data from server